# Time series forecasting with svr in scikit learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, time-series, svm

I have data set of daily temperature indexed by date and I need to predict future temperature using [`SVR`][1] in scikit-learn.

I'm stuck with selecting the `X` and `Y` of the training and `X` of testing
set. For example if I want to predict `Y` at time `t` then I need the
training set to contain the `X` & `Y` at `t-1, t-2, ..., t-N` where `N` is the number of previous days used to predict `Y` at `t`.

How can I do that?

here is it.

```
df=daily_temp1
# define function for create N lags
def create_lags(df, N):
    for i in range(N):
        df['datetime' + str(i+1)] = df.datetime.shift(i+1)
        df['dewpoint' + str(i+1)] = df.dewpoint.shift(i+1)
        df['humidity' + str(i+1)] = df.humidity.shift(i+1)
        df['pressure' + str(i+1)] = df.pressure.shift(i+1)
        df['temperature' + str(i+1)] = df.temperature.shift(i+1)
    df['vism' + str(i+1)] = df.vism.shift(i+1)
    df['wind_direcd' + str(i+1)] = df.wind_direcd.shift(i+1)
    df['wind_speed' + str(i+1)] = df.wind_speed.shift(i+1)
    df['wind_direct' + str(i+1)] = df.wind_direct.shift(i+1)

    return df

# create 10 lags
df = create_lags(df,10)


# the first 10 days will have missing values. can't use them.
df = df.dropna()

# create X and y
y = df['temperature']
X = df.iloc[:, 9:]

# Train on 70% of the data
train_idx = int(len(df) * .7)

# create train and test data
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = X[:train_idx], y[:train_idx], X[train_idx:], y[train_idx:]


# fit and predict
clf = SVR()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

clf.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that builds the feature matrix `X` as the simply lag1 - lagN where lag1 is the previous days temperature and lagN is the temperature N days ago.

```
# create fake temperature
df = pd.DataFrame({'temp':np.random.rand(500)})

# define function for create N lags
def create_lags(df, N):
    for i in range(N):
        df['Lag' + str(i+1)] = df.temp.shift(i+1)
    return df

# create 10 lags
df = create_lags(df,10)

# the first 10 days will have missing values. can't use them.
df = df.dropna()

# create X and y
y = df.temp.values
X = df.iloc[:, 1:].values

# Train on 70% of the data
train_idx = int(len(df) * .7)

# create train and test data
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = X[:train_idx], y[:train_idx], X[train_idx:], y[:train_idx]

# fit and predict
clf = SVR()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

clf.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to fit it to my objective because I also need other features beside the previous temperature but I keep having error TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Comment: scikit learn cannot handle strings. You must convert all strings to numerics. If you have a pandas dataframe, use `pd.get_dummies`. If you are working strictly with sklearn, use `LabelBinarizer` in the preprocessing module.

Comment: I already changed the string ones, Now I have float and datetime datatypes

Comment: datetime         datetime64[ns]
dewpoint                float64
humidity                float64
pressure                float64
temperature             float64
vism                    float64
wind_direcd             float64
wind_speed              float64
wind_direct             float64

Comment: Get rid of the datetime column. There is no point in keeping it in your model. If you absolutely want to keep it for historical purposes, you can use something like the month which might have some predictability. Use `df['datetime'].dt.month`. Basically, every feature must be a numeric (int or float) and not a datetime, string or any other data type.

Comment: Actually I need it for the  C parameter of the SVR, it should change with the difference between the day of the temperature prediction and the previous days, the near the day the more weight it has .. for now I can replace the date by the  difference???

Comment: You do not need it for the C parameter. The C parameter is a single float value that is usually chosen through cross validation. It has nothing to do with the actual values of the features.

Comment: Usually yes, but some studies show that if we make C as variable changes with some feature instead of making it constant then this could improve the accuracy. However for now I just removed the datetime field and I will work on choosing C by cross validation until I have some good results.Then I will go to making C variable.